# imap_fetchheader not getting all

Tags: php, imap, email-headers

ok so i am using imap_fetchheader and its not returning all of them for example i am running this code

```
$uid = imap_uid ($connection->getResource() ,$i );
$t = imap_fetchheader($connection->getResource(),$uid,FT_UID);
```

the header returned from the code:

```
Language: en-US X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04 X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net X-MS-Has-Attach: yes X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1 X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_002_02e8639ffbbd4212bc445f1e6e6f3e79SEHSTE15D1BE4hs20net_"; type="text/html" MIME-Version: 1.0 
Received: from SEHSTE15D5BE2.hs20.net (172.18.251.132) by 
SEHSTE15D5BE4.hs20.net (172.18.251.134) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 
15.0.1178.4 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 15:51:13 +0100 
Received: from SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net (172.18.251.21) by 
SEHSTE15D5BE2.hs20.net (172.18.251.132) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 
15.0.1178.4; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 15:51:12 +0100 
Received: from SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net ([fe80::8bb:6c9a:de89:a8cc]) by 
SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net ([fe80::8bb:6c9a:de89:a8cc%25]) with mapi id 
15.00.1178.000; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 15:51:12 +0100 
From: Calvin Streeting <calvin.streeting@xxx.xxx> 
To: Calvin Streeting <calvin.streeting@xxx.xxx> 
Subject: test4 
Thread-Topic: test4 
Thread-Index: AdIHhHCpJPD3oyumTl+eoisxAbY8qw== 
Date: Mon, 5 Sep 2016 15:51:12 +0100 
Message-ID: <02e8639ffbbd4212bc445f1e6e6f3e79@SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net> 
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US 
Content-Language: en-US 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net 
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1 
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
boundary="_002_02e8639ffbbd4212bc445f1e6e6f3e79SEHSTE15D1BE4hs20net_"; 
type="text/html"
```

but the header in outlook is more

```
Received: from SEHSTE15D5BE5.hs20.net (172.18.251.135) by
 SEHSTE15D5BE4.hs20.net (172.18.251.134) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 15.0.1178.4 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 16:16:27 +0100
Received: from SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net (172.18.251.21) by
 SEHSTE15D5BE5.hs20.net (172.18.251.135) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 15.0.1178.4; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 16:16:27 +0100
Received: from SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net ([fe80::8bb:6c9a:de89:a8cc]) by
 SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net ([fe80::8bb:6c9a:de89:a8cc%25]) with mapi id
 15.00.1178.000; Mon, 5 Sep 2016 16:16:27 +0100
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Calvin Streeting <calvin.streeting@xxx.xxx>
To: Calvin Streeting <calvin.streeting@xxx.xxx>
Subject: test 4
Thread-Topic: test 4
Thread-Index: AdIHiHZMaWKqG5ysTqaZT9s+YSD9Vw==
Date: Mon, 5 Sep 2016 16:16:26 +0100
Message-ID: <2a7ac219c47c42cda107f11afaed50ca@SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <2a7ac219c47c42cda107f11afaed50ca@SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net>
bg-number: 20000
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-FromEntityHeader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Originating
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SEHSTE15D1BE4.hs20.net
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-Originating-IP: [88.98.71.161]
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 544eff45-7473-4111-9fed-08d3d59f9b4f
Return-Path: calvin.streeting@xxx.xxx
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Enterprise: 1.0
X-EXCLAIMER-MD-CONFIG: 266e7a57-cddd-49fd-bdea-19bca6d40303
X-MS-Exchange-ABP-GUID: 804901cb-1d9a-430b-b258-77c8123a6d9c
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Recipient-P2-Type: Bcc
```

any idea why? 
php version is PHP 5.6.9  running on a standard opensue lamp server..

and now i have to add alot of text as this form says most of the text is code so i need to add more details. not sure what else to add :) as quite simply imap_fetchheader dose not seem to give me all the headers that i can see in oultook

Comment: sorry got wrong email in outlook but as sent many test messages and only thing differnet is id. but i cannot edit the q to past other outlook header

Comment: Exchange may "add" more headers when used with Outlook (as it does not use IMAP)

Comment: ok i am going to download and parse file using php_mailparse.. although for some reason today it finds full header... so WTF :)  so how do i close this.?